# Having trouble with indexOf(string name) method. Java

Tags: java

```
/**
* return the index of the Predator with the given name.  Case does not  matter.

* No External Classes Permitted to Be Used in This Method Apart from 
* String.Equals and String.ToUpperCase
* My Solution Length in Lines (note yours can be longer or shorter): 4
*
* @param name the name of the Predator to be found
* @return the position of the searched for Predator.  -1 if none found
*/

public int indexOf(String name) {

}
```

I know what I have to do but I am not sure how to go about solving it. So I know I have to loop through the array and see if the name equals the name in that element, if it does return the INDEX (the position). Can someone please help?

Comment: what exactly you wanna do ?

Comment: u have array of strings ?

Comment: plz help us with your code what you have achieved and also be more particular about the issue you are facing in your code

Comment: Just create a for loop with a index and return that index, it the `Predator` at the given index has an appropriate name. Where is the issue???

Comment: I think you are missing an argument. Probably the task was to search for a given _name_ that happens to be embedded in a given  _intput string_

Comment: ok so the array is of Monsters(predators) the array is called PredatorList. the problem im having is that i don't know how to loop my code so it returns the index, while the case does not matter.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear what help you're looking for from us.  Please consider this SO Question Checklist: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need to have the string array. All you need to do is to loop through every string and compare it with the name. If the case does not matter, you have to compare uppercased strings. Here is my proposition:

```
public int indexOf(String[] array, String name) { 
    for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
        if (array[i].toUpperCase().equals(name.toUpperCase()))
            return i;       
    return -1;
}
```